# Export of exclusions for code coverage and issues in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to export exclusions for code coverage and issues in sonarqube from one project and import to other project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusions are Project Properties, so you could use `/api/properties` Web Service to automatically get these properties from one project and set them on another project.

For example, to migrate code coverage exclusion (property `sonar.coverage.exclusions`, as shown in the Settings UI) from project `foo` to project `bar`:

- get the value from project `foo` :

  > curl http://_your_sonarqube_/api/properties/sonar.coverage.exclusions?resource=foo&format=json
- set the same value on project `bar`

  > curl -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://_your_sonarqube_/api/properties?id=sonar.coverage.exclusions&value=_value_from_foo_&resource=bar'

(where *value_from_foo* is the value you obtained from the first Web Service call above)

Comment: The API path is now `api/settings/values`